# Getting rule property from Yii model

Tags: yii

Maybe the question is easy, but I did not find the answer

In my model I have rule:

```
array('name', 'length', 'max'=>65),
```

In my view I have code:

```
$form->textField($model,'name');
```

After rendering i have:

```
<input id="name" type="text" value="" maxlength="65" name="name">
```

Everything fine, but is it possible to get max length property from model on view page?
I what to show max length somewhere on the page, but i can't get this property.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($model->getValidators('name') as $validator) {
    if ($validator instanceof CStringValidator && $validator->max !== null) {
        echo 'this is the max length ' . $validator->max;
        break;
    }
}
```

This would return all validators for the 'name' attribute. Then search for the `CStringValidator` and return the max size.

Comment: In Yii2 `getValidators()` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: You can use `getActiveValidators()` with an argument in Yii2. Which is better because it only returns the applicable validator(s).

Comment: I had to add the full path of the validator class to make it work in yii2 (if ($validator instanceof \yii\validators\StringValidator ... )

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$model->getValidators('name');
```

which would return you array of validators applied to 'name' attribute. Then find StringValidator and its field named 'max', for this example.